# Simple diagnostic inference in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to do the following in Prolog: given the list of diseases knowledge base:

```
symptom(x, a).
symptom(x, b).
symptom(x, c).
symptom(y, b).
symptom(y, d).
symptom(z, c).
symptom(z, e).
```

Now, given a list of symptoms `[a, b]`, diagnose the possible diseases:

```
diagnose(Symptom, Issue) :- symptom(Issue, Symptom).
diagnose([S|Tail], Issue) :- diagnose(S, Issue), diagnose(Tail, Issue).
```

Running this through SWI-Prolog, I received:

```
?- diagnose([a,b], Issue).
false.
```

Expected:

```
Issue = x
```

Question 1: what am I doing wrongly?
Question 2: how do I modify it to return both x and y? I.e. all the potential diseases that contain at least one of the given symptoms?

Comment: `diagnose(S, Issue); diagnose(Tail, Issue).` returns Issue = x, Issue = x, Issue = y

Comment: Well, your `symptom` facts deal with one symptom. But your predicate `diagnose(Symptom, Issue) :- symptom(Issue, Symptom)` attempts to match single symptoms to an entire list when you call, `diagnose([a, b], Issue)`. Prolog won't automatically match an element to a list of elements for you. If you only need to match at least one of the symptoms, you could use `diagnose(Symptoms, Issues) :- setof(Issue, (member(Symptom, Symptoms), symptom(Issue, Symptom)), Issues).`